# To show a analytic map is zero from a property regarding logarithmic integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $F$ be analytic on $\mathbb{H}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\},$ continuous upto $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ and bounded on each of the half plane $\{Im(z)\geq h>0\}.$ How to show that if $F$ satisfies
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(|F(x+i)|)}{1+x^2}dx=-\infty$$
then $F$ is identically zero on $\mathbb{H}?$

Comment: This is Jensen's inequality in disguise: map your half-plane conformally onto the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks. Now I get it...